# Javascript add attribute to XMLSerializer response

Tags: javascript, xml

I am loading SVGs dynamically and want to add an id attribute to the SVG before inserting in the page.

```
      $.get( "/images/svg/myCodedImage.svg", function( data ) {
          var s = new XMLSerializer();
          $('#mysvg').replaceWith(s.serializeToString(data));
      });
```

I am trying to avoid having a wrapping element with the id - I want to replace the div with the SVG and give that SVG the same id.

Looked around but could not figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute when you have access to the parsed Document, before converting it to string:

```js
$.get( 'data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="30" height="30"/></svg>', function( data ) {
  // data is a Document, we can use DOM operations on it
  data.documentElement.id = "mysvg";
  var s = new XMLSerializer();
  $('#mysvg').replaceWith(s.serializeToString(data));
});
```

```css
#mysvg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mysvg"></div>
```

If you needed to target a deeper element, with a more complex selector, or to perform more complex edits you could even use jQuery over that Document too:

```js
$.get( 'data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="30" height="30"/></svg>', function( data ) {
  data.documentElement.id = "mysvg";
  // the second argument of `$()` is the context
  $("rect", data).attr({
    stroke: "red",
    x: 2,
    y: 2
  });
  var s = new XMLSerializer();
  $('#mysvg').replaceWith(s.serializeToString(data));
});
```

```css
#mysvg {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mysvg"></div>
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. I was trying all kinds of things like SetAttribute and a bunch of other stuff.